# "End If without block If" error

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a problem with Excek VBA. The following part of my code returns the error code "End If without block If". But I can not see why. I searched the internet, but still can not find what the problem is. About the code: I want to open two folders and find the file in folder 1 (Controlfolder) with the filename containing the string "ROI_3". When found, I want to open it and find the file in the other folder (Treatedfolder) with the name containing "ROI_3". Later, I want to do calculations using data from both files. Below you can see the relevant part of the code.

```
Do While ControlFile <> ""

        If InStr(ControlFile, "ROI_3") > 0 Then
            Workbooks(ControlFile).Open
            Exit Do
            TreatedFile = Dir(TreatedFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)
                Do While TreatedFile <> ""
                If InStr(TreatedFile, "ROI_3") > 0 Then
                    Workbooks(TreatedFile).Open
                    Exit Do
                End If
        End If
        ControlFile = Dir
Loop
```

Kind regards

Ferenc

Comment: You do not use `Loop` for second `Do While` loop. Can you check it?

Comment: You cannot use two Dir commands like that. The second cancels the first.

Comment: harun24h: You are right, I forgot to "finish" the second while loop.

Comment: Jeeped: Thanks for your comment, I will read more about the Dir command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the bellow should work, you have two do's with only one loop, also I moved the end if up to end the first if, should work. Let me know.

```
Do While ControlFile <> ""

            If InStr(ControlFile, "ROI_3") > 0 Then
            Workbooks(ControlFile).Open
            Exit Do
            End If
            TreatedFile = Dir(TreatedFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)
                Do While TreatedFile <> ""
                If InStr(TreatedFile, "ROI_3") > 0 Then
                    Workbooks(TreatedFile).Open
                    Exit Do
                End If

        ControlFile = Dir


Loop
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the "End If" problem. Now there is a problem with "ControlFile=Dir". I will try to fix it and I will introduce to the end of the second while loop "Treatedfile=Dir" after reading more about the Dir command (this problem has been pointed out by Jeeped.

Comment: As your original query was resolved with this answer, please consider accepting this answer and start a new query if you need to

Comment: Thanks, I am doing that now.